# How to set unfixed height for elements in Scaffold

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

Is there a way to set height of elements in a `Scaffold` to be exactly the same? I want both the top bar and the content to occupy half of the screen's height

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
             MyLargeTopAppBar(modifier = Modifier.height(1f))
    },
    content = {
            LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.padding(it).height(1f)) {
                ...
            }
    },
    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
)
```

**Arthur Kasparian's suggestion**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip using a scaffold if none of its other elements are needed, the layout then simply becomes a column like so:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    TopAppBar(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .weight(1f)
    ) {}

    Content(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .weight(1f)
    )
}
```

Comment: Please see screenshot in my question, your suggestion is not fully working as the Text in my TopAppBar is not appearing

Comment: Did you copy the code provided in my answer exactly as it was? If so you should specify the text parameter (or content, depending on the composable you are using) for it to show, I left it blank in my answer as it is dependent on you and your app!

Answer (score 1):

The height of the content body is determined in part by the topBar body height, and the weight setter is inaccessible in those scopes, so I don't think it's possible. However what you can do is simply include the top bar in the content:

```
val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
val screenHeight = configuration.screenHeightDp.dp
val size = screenHeight / 2
Scaffold(
    content = {
        Column {
            TopAppBar(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(size)
                    .weight(1f)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                Text("$size")
            }
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(size)
                    .weight(1f)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.Red)
            ) {
                Text("$size")
            }
        }
    },
)
```

You get something like this:
[image]